# iOS 6.0 maps crashing occassionally

Tags: ios, ios6, apple-maps

My app is working fine on iOS 5.0 but when I run the same on iOS 6.0 it's crashing occassionally, two instances I have noticed are:

1. Sometimes when coming back from the MapViewController, OR
2. When I come out of the app, disable location services of the app and open the app again.

But this does not happen always. Below is what is getting displayed on the console, tried searching for a solution and even though found quite a few iOS 6.0 crash posts, could not rectify the crash.

```
Dec  6 20:06:51 iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[896] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/F8E3963A-2678-4698-B5B9-2F2BB42D82B3 (sandbox)
Dec  6 20:06:58 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Dec  6 20:07:08 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
Dec  6 20:07:16 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Dec  6 20:07:26 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
Dec  6 20:08:36 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Dec  6 20:08:39 iPhone MyApp[896] <Warning>: MESH TOO LARGE!!! VKRoadTile: Too many road points for tile 1465.949.11 (512)
Dec  6 20:08:46 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
Dec  6 20:09:37 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Dec  6 20:09:47 iPhone locationd[41] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
Dec  6 20:10:07 iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
Dec  6 20:10:16 iPhone awdd[905] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Dec  6 20:10:16 iPhone awdd[905] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
Dec  6 20:10:20 iPhone ReportCrash[906] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[896]
Dec  6 20:10:20 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.cert.mobile.MyApp[0xce94][896]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.cert.Mobile.MyApp[0xce94]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Dec  6 20:10:20 iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.Cert.mobile.MyApp[0xce94]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Dec  6 20:10:20 iPhone ReportCrash[906] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Dec  6 20:10:20 iPhone ReportCrash[906] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2012-12-06-201019_iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

**This seems to be recurring before a crash**: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary

Why does this happen on iOS 6.0 and how should I fix it? What happens when the following message appears : "Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary"?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: My question is why does the crash happen on iOS 6 only? And how to fix it? What exactly happens when the iPhone "Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary" message shows? Even checked if there was a memory leak, still nothing.